# How would I detect user activities? | discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that when a command is entered it detects a users activities. I wrote some code, but the response from the bot I get is not what I wanted. That's my code:

```
from discord import Member
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.command()
async def status(ctx):
    await ctx.send(Member.activities)

bot.run('token')
```

And this is what I get in response:

> <member 'activities' of 'Member' objects>

How can I fix this? Would anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are new to python. Python is an object oriented programming language, means that you need to make the difference between a class and an instance.

In your case, you are fetching the class attribute, though you want the instance attribute.

What you wanted to do:

```py
@bot.command
async def status(ctx):
  await ctx.send(ctx.author.activities)
```

Though, that would send a python-formatted list, so that's still not what you want.

What I guess you want to do:

```py
@bot.command
async def status(ctx):
  await ctx.send(ctx.author.activities[0].name)
```

Please note, you need more code as this command like that would raise an error if the member doesn't have any activity.